# Next button in devise does not go the next path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redirect, devise

Signup "Next" button doesn't redirect me to second form

Hello, I having a hard time understanding why the next button doesn't go to the next page. The paths work alone, but in each path when I fill the fields and click on "Next" it doesn't go to the next path. It doesn't do anything actually.
**Here is the controller:**

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  def personal_info
    @user = User.new
    render 'devise/registrations/personal_info'
  end

  def create_personal_info
    @user = User.new(personal_info_params)
    if @user.valid?(:personal_info)
      session[:user] = @user.attributes
      if @user.save
        redirect_to new_user_registration_photo_path
      else
        render 'devise/registrations/personal_info'
      end
    else
      render 'devise/registrations/personal_info'
    end
  end

  def photo
    @user = User.new
    render 'devise/registrations/photo'
  end

  def create_photo
    @user = User.new(photo_params)
    if @user.valid?(:photo)
      session[:user].merge!(@user.attributes)
      if @user.save
        redirect_to new_user_registration_account_details_path
      else
        render 'devise/registrations/photo'
      end
    else
      render 'devise/registrations/photo'
    end
  end

  def account_details
    @user = User.new
    render 'devise/registrations/account_details'
  end

  def create_account_details
    @user = User.new(account_details_params)
    if @user.valid?(:account_details)
      @user.attributes = session[:user]
      if @user.save
        session[:user] = nil
        sign_in(@user)
        redirect_to root_path
      else
        render 'devise/registrations/account_details'
      end
    else
      render 'devise/registrations/account_details'
    end
  end

  private

  def personal_info_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :surname, :email, :phone, :birthday, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end

  def photo_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:photo)
  end

  def account_details_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:interests, :skillset, language_skills: [])
  end
end
```

**Here is the first view**

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: create_user_registration_personal_info_path) do |f| %>

  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>

  <%= f.label :email %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>
 
  <%= f.label :password %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>


  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>


  <%= f.submit 'Next' %>
<% end %>
```

**Here are the routes**

```
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    registrations: 'users/registrations'
  }

  devise_scope :user do
    get '/sign_up/personal_info', to: 'users/registrations#personal_info', as: :new_user_registration_personal_info
    post '/sign_up/personal_info', to: 'users/registrations#create_personal_info', as: :create_user_registration_personal_info
    get '/sign_up/photo', to: 'users/registrations#photo', as: :new_user_registration_photo
    post '/sign_up/photo', to: 'users/registrations#create_photo', as: :create_user_registration_photo
    get '/sign_up/account_details', to: 'users/registrations#account_details', as: :new_user_registration_account_details
    post '/sign_up/account_details', to: 'users/registrations#create_account_details', as: :create_user_registration_account_details
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are there other of these parameters mandatory in the User model pointed in personal_info_params?

```
def personal_info_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :surname, :email, :phone, :birthday, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
```

In the view you're passing only name, email, password, password_confirmation, and my assumption is that that model User expects these params present

Comment: Thanks! I believe this was the problem.